# Newer version of pngquant?

Tags: apt

Hopefully I'm ok asking this here (I was going to put it on SO, but decided it was probably better placed here)

I've done a fair bit of Googling, to try and figure this out myself - but am not coming up with anything. I've installed **pngquant** using:

`sudo apt-get install pngquant`

Thats ok - apart from the version number:

```
pngquant, version 1.0 of 5 April 2002, by Greg Roelofs.
   Compiled with libpng 1.2.46; using libpng 1.2.49.
   Compiled with zlib 1.2.3.4; using zlib 1.2.7.
```

From what I have read, we need to be using version **2.0** (as *1.0* is quite lossy and the version is over 10 years old). How do you go about forcing it to use the latest one? I'm on Debian 7 , if that's any help.

**UPDATE** I've decided to keep with the 1.0 version (as I'm not comfortable upgrading to Debian 8.1 yet). However, the silly thing is refusing to work:

```
root@#serever: pngquant -ext .png -force 256 test.png
pngquant, version 1.0 of 5 April 2002, by Greg Roelofs.
   Compiled with libpng 1.2.46; using libpng 1.2.49.
   Compiled with zlib 1.2.3.4; using zlib 1.2.7.

   usage:  pngquant [options] <ncolors> [pngfile [pngfile ...]]
                    [options] -map mapfile [pngfile [pngfile ...]]
   options:
      -force         overwrite existing output files
      -ordered       use ordered dithering (synonyms:  -nofloyd, -nofs)
      -verbose       print status messages (synonyms:  -noquiet)

   Quantizes one or more 32-bit RGBA PNGs to 8-bit (or smaller) RGBA-palette
   PNGs using either ordered dithering or Floyd-Steinberg diffusion dithering
   (default).  The output filename is the same as the input name except that
   it ends in "-fs8.png" or "-or8.png" (unless the input is stdin, in which
   case the quantized image will go to stdout).  The default behavior if the
   output file exists is to skip the conversion; use -force to overwrite.

   NOTE:  the -map option is NOT YET SUPPORTED.
```

As you can see, all it does (no matter what args I pass in), is spit out the help file! I've tried the basics of :

`pngquant foo.png`

...but the same thing. Any ideas?

Comment: Their homepage says you need to upgrade to jessie.

Comment: Oh ok - mmm, maybe I will have to skip it then :( I'm using linode.com, and used an image to set it all up. However, I'm unsure of how to safely upgrade it. Maybe I'll have to come back to it at a later time, and setup a new dev copy of the site, to get it all working before I move live over to it. Please put your reply as an answer, and I will accept it (as it does answer my question, just not quite the one I was hoping for <G>)